# Google sheets: Match and Link values between sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a budget and have one reference sheet that lists all items and their costs.

In the other sheets I want the costs automatically populated if the name of the item is matching the reference sheet.

Example:

In the data sheet I have Elephant (B:4) listed as 109 (B:5) .  In Q1 sheet I need the 109 automatically filled in column B when column A has Elephant listed.

I hope it kinda makes sense

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17vZ9P2jcZSSaFOBYTE9nfT129Y5eepPjSBMt-Hom-tA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey I actually found lookup and it is doing exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A2:index(A2:A, COUNTA(A2:A)), DATA!A2:index(DATA!b2:B, COUNTA(DATA!A2:A)), 2,0))
```

`Banana` is the correct spelling; not `Bannana`